# snmp bandwidth utiliazation on Arista

Tags: arista

Has anyone succeeded with getting bandwidth utilization on the subinterfaces in Arista switch:

Arista DCS-7280CR2A-30-F
Hardware version: 21.01

Because, in my situation, it is only working at the physical interface level, but not on hte subinterface level. for example:
Po17 > works fine
Po17.2 > not working at all

snmpwalk shows 0 in counter , but not sure if this is the problem:

```
[root@monnnmptk ~]# snmpwalk -v2c -c XXX 11.11.11.11 | grep 1074520071
IF-MIB::ifIndex.1074520071 = INTEGER: 1074520071
IF-MIB::ifDescr.1074520071 = STRING: Port-Channel7.2
IF-MIB::ifType.1074520071 = INTEGER: l3ipvlan(136)
IF-MIB::ifMtu.1074520071 = INTEGER: 9192
IF-MIB::ifSpeed.1074520071 = Gauge32: 0
IF-MIB::ifPhysAddress.1074520071 = STRING: 28:99:3a:6:46:75
IF-MIB::ifAdminStatus.1074520071 = INTEGER: up(1)
IF-MIB::ifOperStatus.1074520071 = INTEGER: up(1)
IF-MIB::ifLastChange.1074520071 = Timeticks: (422664792) 48 days, 22:04:07.92
IF-MIB::ifInOctets.1074520071 = Counter32: 0
IF-MIB::ifInUcastPkts.1074520071 = Counter32: 0
IF-MIB::ifInNUcastPkts.1074520071 = Counter32: 0
IF-MIB::ifInDiscards.1074520071 = Counter32: 0
IF-MIB::ifInErrors.1074520071 = Counter32: 0
IF-MIB::ifInUnknownProtos.1074520071 = Counter32: 0
IF-MIB::ifOutOctets.1074520071 = Counter32: 0
IF-MIB::ifOutUcastPkts.1074520071 = Counter32: 0
IF-MIB::ifOutNUcastPkts.1074520071 = Counter32: 0
IF-MIB::ifOutDiscards.1074520071 = Counter32: 0
IF-MIB::ifOutErrors.1074520071 = Counter32: 0
IF-MIB::ifOutQLen.1074520071 = Gauge32: 0
IF-MIB::ifSpecific.1074520071 = OID: SNMPv2-SMI::zeroDotZero
```

Even after setting up hardware counter, we see graph, but the graph is not correct at all

Comment: If it's not reporting numbers when you know there's traffic, it's either (a) not keeping subinterface counters, or (b) SNMP is broken and not reporting them. (my experience is with Cisco, and it's often both... doesn't count, or counts but SNMP won't report them. this was common in the frame-relay days -- fixed in one release, unfixed in the next.)

Comment: There's a good chance that the counters are maintained by the ASIC controlling the port, which would not distinguish between different subinterfaces. If my guess is true, the only counter available is for the whole interface, not each subinterface.